# CakePHP Email Validation

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to perform specific email validation in cakephp?  In my model file, I have

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array( 
    'required' => 'true',
    'rule' => array('email', true),
    'message'=> 'Please supply a valid email address.')
);
```

But I want to be able to enforce the constraint that the email address will end in something specific, for example:

```
@example.com
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a custom one if you are enforcing the constraint on a domain..

```
 public $validate = array(
    'login' => array(
        'rule'    => '/^.+@domain\.com$/i',
        'message' => 'This email address must be @domain.com'
    )
);
```

Comment: Not really - they wanted the specific domain. You could add more validation on the front of it, rather than the end.

Comment: Something like `[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@domain\.com` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @JakeGould your regex accepts `alfa@bravo@example.com` which is not allowed, `"alfa@bravo"@example.com` is allowed though. See the [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) and [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) for more info.

Comment: @JakeGould Yes I see, scroll to the bottom of that page. There an absolute mental regex over there :O Never seen anything like it.